# String split on space and hyphen

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to target every space and hyphen within a string and wrap each word with a span.
This is what I am trying, obviously is not the best way to achieve this. Any ideas?

```
$('.whatsOn').each(function() {
    var date = $(this).find(".time");
    var words = date.text().split(" ");
    date.empty();
    $.each(words, function(i, v) {
       date.append($("<span>").text(v));
    });
  
    var wordsSpan = $(this).find(".time span").text().split("-");
    $(this).find(".time span").empty();
    $.each(words, function(i, v) {
       $(this).find(".time span").append($("<span>").text(v));
    });
});
```

```
<div class="whatsOn">
   <dd class="time">14th-29th July</dd>
</div>
```

Comment: How should your output look like ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you encode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass regular expression to split like this. `date.text().split(/[- ]/);`

```js
$('.whatsOn').each(function() {
  var date = $(this).find(".time");
  var words = date.text().split(/[- ]+/);
  console.log(words)
  date.empty();
  $.each(words, function(i, v) {
    date.append($("<span>").text(v));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<dl class="whatsOn">
  <dd class="time">14th-29th July</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can use regular expression to split the string.

```
var words = date.text().split(/[\s-]+/);
```